# postgresql C input/output function strange behaviour

Tags: c, database, postgresql

Recently I have been working with postgresql and its custom user-define type in C.

Before I get to the implementation of input/output function of my user-define type EmailAddress, here's the strange behaviour

If I insert data from file using **psql -f** option, the email addresses in username column are all messed up.

[image]

but if I insert data from file using **\i data.sql** option within psql [dbname], I'd get this result. all emails are displayed correctly
[image]

---email.c------

```
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
typedef struct EmailAdress {
    char* domain;
    char* local;
} EmailAddress;

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(email_in);
Datum email_in(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
    // Get arg c string
    char* pStr = palloc(strlen(PG_GETARG_CSTRING(0)));
    strcpy(pStr, PG_GETARG_CSTRING(0));

    // Convert to connical form
    int i;
    for (i = 0; pStr[i]; i++) {
        pStr[i] = tolower(pStr[i]);
    }

    EmailAddress* pEmail = (EmailAddress*) palloc(sizeof(EmailAddress));

    char* pToken;
    pToken = strtok(pStr, AT);
    pEmail->local = malloc(strlen(pToken) + 1);
    strcpy(pEmail->local, pToken);

    pToken = strtok(NULL, AT);
    pEmail->domain = malloc(strlen(pToken) + 1);
    strcpy(pEmail->domain, pToken);

    pfree(pStr);

    if (!valid(pEmail)) {
        ereport(ERROR, (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_TEXT_REPRESENTATION), errmsg("invalid EmailAddress: \"%s@%s\" - pointer: %p", pEmail->local, pEmail->domain, pEmail)));
    }

    PG_RETURN_POINTER(pEmail);
}


PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(email_out);
Datum email_out(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
    EmailAddress* pEmail = (EmailAddress *) PG_GETARG_POINTER(0);
    char* pResult = psprintf("%s@%s", pEmail->local, pEmail->domain);

    PG_RETURN_CSTRING(pResult);
}
```

----email.source----

```
CREATE FUNCTION email_in(cstring)
    RETURNS EmailAddress
    AS '_OBJWD_/email'
    LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE FUNCTION email_out(EmailAddress)
    RETURNS cstring
    AS '_OBJWD_/email'
    LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE TYPE EmailAddress (
    internallength   = 16,
    input            = email_in,
    output           = email_out,
    alignment        = double
);


CREATE FUNCTION email_eq(EmailAddress, EmailAddress) RETURNS bool
    AS '_OBJWD_/email' LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE FUNCTION email_neq(EmailAddress, EmailAddress) RETURNS bool
    AS '_OBJWD_/email' LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE FUNCTION email_gt(EmailAddress, EmailAddress) RETURNS bool
    AS '_OBJWD_/email' LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE FUNCTION email_ge(EmailAddress, EmailAddress) RETURNS bool
    AS '_OBJWD_/email' LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE FUNCTION email_lt(EmailAddress, EmailAddress) RETURNS bool
    AS '_OBJWD_/email' LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE FUNCTION email_le(EmailAddress, EmailAddress) RETURNS bool
    AS '_OBJWD_/email' LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE FUNCTION email_deq(EmailAddress, EmailAddress) RETURNS bool
    AS '_OBJWD_/email' LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE FUNCTION email_ndeq(EmailAddress, EmailAddress) RETURNS bool
    AS '_OBJWD_/email' LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE OPERATOR < (
    leftarg = EmailAddress, rightarg = EmailAddress, procedure = email_lt,
    commutator = > , negator = >=
);

CREATE OPERATOR <= (
    leftarg = EmailAddress, rightarg = EmailAddress, procedure = email_le,
    commutator = >= , negator = >
);

CREATE OPERATOR = (
    leftarg = EmailAddress, rightarg = EmailAddress, procedure = email_eq,
    commutator = = , negator = <>
);

CREATE OPERATOR <> (
    leftarg = EmailAddress, rightarg = EmailAddress, procedure = email_neq,
    commutator = <> , negator = =
);

CREATE OPERATOR >= (
    leftarg = EmailAddress, rightarg = EmailAddress, procedure = email_ge,
    commutator = <= , negator = <
);

CREATE OPERATOR > (
    leftarg = EmailAddress, rightarg = EmailAddress, procedure = email_gt,
    commutator = < , negator = <=
);

CREATE OPERATOR ~ (
    leftarg = EmailAddress, rightarg = EmailAddress, procedure = email_deq,
    commutator = ~ , negator = !~
);

CREATE OPERATOR !~ (
    leftarg = EmailAddress, rightarg = EmailAddress, procedure = email_ndeq,
    commutator = !~ , negator = ~
);

CREATE FUNCTION email_cmp(EmailAddress, EmailAddress) RETURNS int4
    AS '_OBJWD_/email' LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE FUNCTION email_hash(EmailAddress) RETURNS int4
    AS '_OBJWD_/email' LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;

-- now we can make the operator class
CREATE OPERATOR CLASS email_btree_ops
    DEFAULT FOR TYPE EmailAddress USING btree AS
        OPERATOR        1       <   ,
        OPERATOR        2       <=  ,
        OPERATOR        3       =   ,
        OPERATOR        4       >=  ,
        OPERATOR        5       >   ,
        FUNCTION        1       email_cmp(EmailAddress, EmailAddress);

CREATE OPERATOR CLASS email_hash_ops
    DEFAULT FOR TYPE EmailAddress USING hash AS
        OPERATOR        1       =   ,
        FUNCTION        1       email_hash(EmailAddress);
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is related, but `strtok` is not re-entrant and you'd probably not want to use it.

Comment: Ah just noticed. You're just storing pointers I guess, so this is not correct at all. It just looks like it works in the second example because you never freed the memory that you malloced for the components. And in the first one you're invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: the only place where I free memory is pfree(pStr) which is just a temporary string pointer.

Comment: Your type is only 16 bytes, how do you suppose postgresql is going to save the actual email addresses in 16 bytes?!

Comment: "this is not correct at all" ? as in my approach is not correct at all?

Comment: exactly, your approach is not correct at all, your type must be a **varlena** type to accommodate for a varying length of an email address.

Comment: does that mean I should also change the structure EmailAddress as well? also how do I declare varlena type?

Comment: I've never done a varlena type myself; you can look for the variable length types at the end of http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/xtypes.html (it is quite terse)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108431/discussion-between-thangdo-and-antti-haapala).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. 
With lots of help and support from wonderful people such as @Antti and my professor,

This is the solution and reason behind this behaviour (in summary):

The problem is here:

```
typedef struct EmailAdress {
    char* domain;
    char* local;
} EmailAddress;
```

The buffers I was allocating for local and domain only exist in the memory context of the original sql process.

What I actually store in the database are pointers to these buffers, and these will work ok while the original sql process is running. When I start a new sql process, I still have the same buffer addresses in the tuple, but the buffers do not exist in the new memory context.

There are two possible solutions:

- one easy but space-inefficient, the other more difficult but also wastes less space.
- one more complicated one but space-efficient (using varlena data type - I couldn't figure out how to implement this approach, so I let it go)

The easy one (which most people have used) is to define the struct as

```
typedef struct EmailAdress {
    char domain[MAX];
    char local[MAX];
} EmailAddress;
```

I then no longer use malloc() for local and domain under this strategy. 
The buffer space for them is created when you do the palloc()

This works because all of the string data is included in the chunk of memory which is created by the palloc(), and thus is written to the disk when PostgreSQL inserts the tuple.

In term of changing email.source accordingly, the only change needed is this:

```
CREATE TYPE EmailAddress (
    internallength   = 258,
    input            = email_in,
    output           = email_out,
    alignment        = int4,
    storage          = plain
);
```

Note the internal length = 258 (129 * 2) because in my case I can assume all local/domain part are 128 bits max + 1 bit for null terminator.